# I have a problem converting int to double

Tags: c#

I'm a beginner programmer and at this moment i try to create primitive program for define variable types.
Below code and core of my problem.

```cs
namespace Moving
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            
            if (int.TryParse(input, out int result1))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("type int");
            }
            if (double.TryParse(input, out double result2))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("type double");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("type String");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

When i use string or double it works normally. But when i input int, works first if{} and second if{} too. For example i input 12. Program writes "type int" and "type double" because int may convert to double without efforts. I don't need it. Can i don't  convert variable int to double? And i haven't a clue how i can explain to program to see difference between "string" and "char". What may do with it?

Comment: try `else if ` instead of just `if`: `else if (double.TryParse(input, out double result2)) {...}`

Comment: That's because a integer is also a double, for example the number `1`, it's obviously an integer, but also a double because (mathematically) `1 = 1.0` is true. You'll want to use `else if` instead of just an `if`. I highly recommend reading the [selection statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/selection-statements#the-if-statement) documentation

Comment: You're going to have to put more logic into how you decide whether the user input is an int or a double in cases where it could reasonably be either

Answer (score 1):

Because (mathematically) `1 = 1.0` is true, knowing this we derive that all integers are also valid *decimal numbers*, in programming terms we call them *floating point numbers*, and `double` is a floating point number type, meaning, it represents a floating point number, and as such can also represent integers<sup>*</sup>. So technically there's no problem, but it's not behaving how we want it to behave, so how do we fix this?

Easy, we use an `else if` statement instead of an `if` statement. The `else if` is only checked if the `if` (or `else if`) before it is false. Implementing it looks like this:

```cs
string input = Console.ReadLine();

if (int.TryParse(input, out int intResult))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Integer");
}
else if (double.TryParse(input, out double doubleResult))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Double");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("String");
}
```

---

<sup>*</sup>Okay, so technically `double` (and every floating point number type) *can't* represent every integer perfectly, because of how they're implemented in binary, but that's a whole other topic and too advanced for now, if you ever want to know more, check out [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/9363973)

Comment: Thank you MindSwipe. I'll look in post about floating point later. I think it's pretty difficult for me now. I'll definitely read it when I'm done with the basics

Comment: @Aleksandr no problem, it really is quite an advanced topic to understand, you'll need to understand binary first and also look at how floating point numbers are implemented in binary before really understanding it

Answer (score 0):

In your statements, there are two different condition blocks. Therefore, you will get two outputs. If you only want to get one output. You should use one condition block: If, Else If, Else.

```
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        
        if (int.TryParse(input, out int result1))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("type int");
        }
        else if (double.TryParse(input, out double result2))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("type double");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("type String");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can try `else if` instead of just `if`. Please, note, that every `int` can be parsed as `double` and every `char` can be treated as `string`:

```
if (int.TryParse(input, out int result1))
    Console.WriteLine("type int");
else if (double.TryParse(input, out double result2))
    Console.WriteLine("type double");
else if (input.Length == 1) // char is a string of Length == 1
    Console.WriteLine("type char");
else
    Console.WriteLine("type String");
```

Comment: Well. Thank you Dmitry.
I am surprised that answer so short and simple. it's amazing!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Convert` class to Convert `int` to `double`

```
int n1 = 289;
double n2;
n2 = Convert.ToDouble(n1);
```